# How do I change the URL's of SharePoint list items after I have changed the name and URL of the list itself?

Tags: sharepoint

I successfully went into designer and changed the url and name of a SharePoint list from A --> B. However the items in the list still have the name "A" in the url so they will not open anymore now that the url of the list is B. I have a few thousand items in the list so is there anyway to make the change in the list name reflect in the url of the items as well?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try renaming it through SharePoint Designer to see if does the job the UI left incomplete.

A harder way to achieve the same objective would be saving the list as a template (including its contents), creating a new list based on that template using the desired name, and then deleting the original list.

Here is the procedure to saving and creating lists as templates:

https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393#bmcreate